# Draw mesh using material with different colors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, drawable, mesh

I am making a grid based game. For it I need to debug certain tiles, for example where there is a collision and where the player is aiming. I have made a debugger class that draws a square mesh at a position using a color.

```
public class GridDebugger : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private float alpha;

    private Mesh mesh;
    private Material mat;

    void Start() {
        mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));
        mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.vertices = new Vector3[] { new Vector3(.5f, .5f, 0), new Vector3(.5f, -.5f), new Vector3(-.5f, -.5f), new Vector3(-.5f, .5f) };
        mesh.triangles = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0 };
    }

    public void Debug(Vector3 position, Color color) {
        color.a = alpha;
        mat.color = color;
        Graphics.DrawMesh(mesh, position, Quaternion.identity, mat, 0);
    }
}
```

Currently the class has two users:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(GridDebugger))]
public class CollisionSystem : GridSystem {
    private List<Node>[,] grid;
    private GridDebugger debugger;

    void Awake() {
        debugger = GetComponent<GridDebugger>();
    }

    //Logic....

    void Update() {
        if (grid != null) {
            for (int x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(0); x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < grid.GetLength(1); y++) {
                    if (grid[x, y] != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < grid[x, y].Count; i++) {
                            if (grid[x,y][i].Parent.Debug) {
                                Vector3 worldPos = GridToWorldPos(new Vector2Int(x, y), grid.GetLength(0), grid.GetLength(1));
                                worldPos.z = -0.0001f;
                                debugger.Debug(worldPos, Color.Red);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }     
}
```

And

```
public class GridMeleeWeapon : MonoBehaviour {
    private GridDebugger debugger;

    void Awake() {
        debugger = FindObjectOfType<GridDebugger>();
    }    

    public void Aim(Vector2 dir) {
        Vector3 position = transform.position + dir;
        debugger.Debug(position, Color.blue);                 
    }
}
```

In `CollisionSystem` I loop every collider and draw a red square at every position.
In `GridMeleeWeapon` I just draw a blue square where the player aims.

The issue is that every square is drawn with the color used in `CollisionSystem` i.e red. When drawing the blue squares in `GridMeleeWeapon` they turn out red. If I remove `debugger.Debug(worldPos, Color.Red)` in `CollisionSystem` the squares I draw from `GridMeleeWeapon` are displayed blue.

With the current code I can't seem to draw meshes of different colors. What I think is happening is that the color specified by the first caller are used for consecutive calls, even though the color of the material is changed but why I have no idea.

How do I set the color correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material in Unity 3D is a reference type.

Your code in `GridMeleeWeapon` and `CollisionSystem` use the same instance of `GridDebugger` and material. What happens is since you change the material color `OnUpdate()` it will change the color from blue to red instantly (every frame) on each object using this material.

Instead of passing a color to your `debugger().Debug()` method, pass a material with a different color. For instance create a material with color red and another material with color blue. Use these materials to set the color.

Comment: Okay, so the material is used as a reference when the mesh is drawn? That makes sence, thank you.

Comment: Yes, Material in Unity 3D is a class and therefore it is a reference type.